# Undefined is not an object (eveluating 'e.foreach') react native map function

Tags: react-native

I want to show user clicked category in text box. So I am using `onPress={() => this.setState({ onPressItem: category.name })}`. But I am getting error as `Undefined is not an object (eveluating 'e.foreach')` What am I missing here?

```
  export default class MyShowroom extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          onPressItem: 'shirt',
          categories: [{displayName: 'Shirt', name: 'shirt', uri: 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/shirt.png'},
                     {displayName: 'belt', name: 'belt', uri: 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/belt.png'},
                     {displayName: 'blazer', name: 'blazer', uri: 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Blazer.png'}]
        }
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <Row>
          <View style={styles.title}>
            <Text style={styles.show}>My Showroom</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', padding: 50}}>
          {
            this.state.categories.map((category, i) => {
              return(
               <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity = { .5 } key={i} onPress={() => this.setState({ onPressItem: category.name })}>
                 <Image source={{uri: category.uri}} style= {styles.categoryImage}/>
                 <Text key={i} style={styles.categoryText}>{category.displayName} </Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>);
           })
          }
         </View>
      </Row>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How you set data into this.state.categories ?  I think because it's undefined when component mount

Comment: Inside constructor. Sorry I edited my question

Comment: please post some code, where are you calling the .map function? Is it inside your render function?

Comment: @IsaacSekamatte I have updated my question. Kindly check it

Comment: run your source code, and it is working well.

Comment: Not sure why it is giving error at my end. Could you please show your results?

Comment: Could try follow this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14079#issuecomment-314327806) ?

Comment: @IsaacSekamatte I posted separate question regarding this with full code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781149/react-native-super-grid-refresh-grid-during-callback Could you please check it?